# Given $f(x)=3x+2$ and $g(x)=2x^2-1$ find the following and state if the composite function exists.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

> Given $f(x)=3x+2$ and $g(x)=2x^2-1$ find the following and state if the composite function exists.

$$(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$$

$$f(2x^2-1)=3x+2$$

$$(f\circ g)(x)=3(2x^2-1)+2$$

Do I stop here? Or continue to get $6x^2 -1$?

Yes it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how much you simplify mathematically, though a teacher might care. Yes, you've calculated the composition of the functions.